# uploadify shows upload successful, no file in folder

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have read all of the previous posts regarding uploadify stating that the upload was successful but no file was uploaded, none of the solutions worked. Could someone take a look at the code as see if i am missing something. Also i ran a phpinfo() and it said my file upload is on. I am using uploadify 3.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Uploadify Implementation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'
            // Your options here
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
</body>
</html>
```

> ```
> // Define a destination
> $targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root
>
> if (!empty($_FILES)) {
>   $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
>   $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
>   $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
>
>   // Validate the file type
>   $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
>   $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
>
>   if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
>       move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
>       echo '1';
>   } else {
>       echo 'Invalid file type.';
>   }
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: `$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']` instead of `$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']`

Comment: just tried that and same result. anything else? is it a problem with my php?

Comment: does target path is correct and have permission ?

Comment: I set the permission to full. the "uploads" folder is located in the root folder with all the other files.

Comment: Is there a way to run a test and see if the uploadify.php is even being executed?

Comment: run this into firefox and check firebug. firebug show ajax request

Comment: i am stuck i have tried everything i can think of and still cant get it to work!

Comment: @JohnMarsh - Did you ever get it to work?